# Arraylist of objects - how to add objects with duplicate values

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `Dog` that looks like this,

```
ArrayList<Dog> array=new ArrayList<>();

   array.add(new Dog("one", 10));
   array.add(new Dog("two", 20));
   array.add(new Dog("one", 40));
```

Class `Dog` takes a String and a Double as parameters.I'm trying to merge those ArrayList objects that have duplicate `String` values.At the same time i need to add their `Double` values. So in this example i want to get a new ArrayList that will have two Dog objects like this,

```
Dog ("one", 50)
Dog ("two", 20)
```

I've already managed to add objects with duplicate values but i'm having trouble in adding their double values.Any suggestions?

Comment: iterate over the list. A dog with this String already exists? add the integer, else, add the dog

Comment: I would use a map with `Map<String, Dog>` where the `String` is the dogs name. Using a list needs more work to handle the duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine the dogs using `Map.merge` and a remapping function:

```
Map<String,Dog> map = new HashMap<>();
array.stream().forEach(dog -> map.merge(dog.name, dog, (d1, d2) -> {
    return new Dog(d1.name, d1.count + d2.count);
}));

ArrayList<Dog> mergedDogs = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Map to track Dog objects as you encounter them while you go through the List one by one in a for loop.

```
List<Dog> array=new ArrayList<>();

array.add(new Dog("one", 10));
array.add(new Dog("two", 20));
array.add(new Dog("two", 120));
array.add(new Dog("one", 40));

Map<String, Dog> map = new HashMap<>(); //Map with key=StringField and value=Dog object

for(Dog d : array){

    Dog dog = map.get(d.getStringField()); 
    if(dog != null){ //If dog object is already in map
        dog.setDoubleField(dog.getDoubleField()+d.getDoubleField()); //add the double value of d to it.
    }else{
        map.put(d.getStringField(), d); //add the dog object with key as stringField
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(map.values().toArray()));
```